# Events are getting aligned on wrong dates when fetching for all users

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

We are using fullcalendar.js for rendering the events that is attendance of all employees. We have created an api that fetch all users details and specific user details as well. For single user the events are rendered properly. But when rendering for all users, events are rendered at wrong places.

When sorted by specific user:
[image]

When sorted for all employee:
[image]

Santosh entry for 1 aug when sorted by all employee that entry is for 6 aug but rendering at wrong place. Events data and date are verified and they are proper, But still the dates are wrongly placed. Request all to please guide on this.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          defaultDate: Date(),
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events:function(start,end,timezone,callback){
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost:8000/admin/employee/attendance/0",
              method: "GET",
              success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                var events = [];
                var attendance =res.data;
                attendance.forEach(function(item){
                
                  var d = new Date(item.work_in);
                  console.log(d.toISOString());
                  events.push({
                    title : item.emp.name,
                    start : d.toISOString()
                  })
                });
                console.log(events);
                callback(events);
              }
            })
          },
          eventClick: function(info) {
              info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); // don't let the browser navigate
              // console.log("hi");
              if (info.event.url) {
                  window.open(info.event.url);
              }
          }
        });
```

Event data sample:

```
[
  { "title": "Omkar Babrekar", "start": "2021-08-03T04:34:00.000Z" }, 
  { "title": "Santosh Upadhayay", "start": "2021-08-06T07:41:00.000Z" }, 
  { "title": "Omkar Babrekar", "start": "2021-08-02T06:37:00.000Z" }, 
  { "title": "Omkar Babrekar", "start": "2021-08-06T04:30:00.000Z" }, 
  { "title": "Omkar Babrekar", "start": "2021-08-28T07:35:00.000Z" }, 
  { "title": "Omkar Babrekar", "start": "2021-08-27T07:36:00.000Z" } 
]
```

Comment: `Events data and date are verified and they are proper`... `But still the dates are wrongly placed`... These two statements contradict each other. One of them isn't true, otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question. I suggest you double check everything. If you need help with that, show us the relevant bits of JSON event data you're sending to fullCalendar

Comment: P.s. the way you're adding events to the calendar is weird and inefficient. I suggest reading https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function

Comment: [
    {
        "title": "Omkar Babrekar",
        "start": "2021-08-03T04:34:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "title": "Santosh Upadhayay",
        "start": "2021-08-06T07:41:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "title": "Omkar Babrekar",
        "start": "2021-08-02T06:37:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "title": "Omkar Babrekar",
        "start": "2021-08-06T04:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "title": "Omkar Babrekar",
        "start": "2021-08-28T07:35:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "title": "Omkar Babrekar",
        "start": "2021-08-27T07:36:00.000Z"
    }
]

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ADyson But i tried both ways mentioned by you still it is going on wrong way. Also posted the json that am posting to events source. Still events are diplayed at wrong dates.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it might be a timezone issue. You've got timezones switched off in fullCalendar (the default), but you're putting a Z on the end of the events to indicate the time is being expressed in UTC. Therefore I think when displayed they'll be expressed in the local timezone. They all appear to be 5.5 hours ahead of the time shown in the JSON. Is your local timezone 5.5 hours ahead of UTC? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timezone explains the different approaches you can take to resolve it.

Comment: I am sorry but @ADyson it doesn't works like that but we identified that when a day has more than one event then it is not displaying at correct place. When added just one it works fine

Comment: Really? Because that isn't what is shown in your screehots, or in this demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJgywPz?editors=0010 . All the events in your screenshot which came from the JSON are showing 5.5 hours ahead. It doesn't matter how many events are in the day. But for me, my timezone is the same as UTC so I see them at the same time as the JSON shows. If that's not the problem you're having then you haven't given me an example of the real problem.

Comment: Hi @ADyson we have sorted vthat issue by properly importing vendors file. Issue was for single date it was loading event a proper place but for multiple event on same date it was showing issue. Hence we imported all vendor files first then we excuted that resolves our issue. I am thank full to you for your support and guidance.